# Pager control doesnt submit other form fields on next/previous actions?

Tags: xpages

I have a view on the page with pager which works nice, and I have also a text field bound to viewScope variable but now I have found out, that when I enter the text into text field and then click on previous/next pager buttons it does server turnaround (the same for full and partial refresh defined for pager) the view is switched to another page correctly but the text field variable is lost. In the browser dev tools I can see the variable is posted to the server correctly but its not bound to the field and after page refresh  the text field is blank. I have put code to view this viewScope variable on server console in afterRestoreView event but its realy empty. Can someone help me to understand how is the pager supposed to work with combination with other form fields?

Comment: Just tried to access the component value directly (e.g. getComponent("selectedIds").getValue()) after pager issued submision, but there is no submited value available. Its very strange. For partial refresh defined for the pager it also refreshes the entire form so values in text fields get lost :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I have enabled partial refresh for pager and put xp:panel around the pager and view. All the input fields are now outside this panel. During the pager navigation the partial refresh process updates only the nearest parent panel and rest of the fields remains unchanged on html. And this is what I want ...